# Wrap python list to unsigned char*

Tags: c++, python, swig, unsigned-char

Edit : Hi all !!

I'm currently trying to access to C++ functions from Python and I'm facing to a problem when I try to pass Python list as argument to a function.

here is the C++ function definition I'm trying to access (used to send command to PC/SC reader) :

```
SRpdu *SendAPDU(unsigned int uiAPDU, //Command
                unsigned int ucLE,   //Data expected for response
                unsigned int ucLC,   //Size of data buffer
                unsigned char * pucDataBuf = 0); //data buffer
```

My goal is to call this function as following from python like in example below. The goal is to convert the list [1,2,3] to a unsigned char * buffer :

```
SendAPDU(0x01020304, 0, 3, [1, 2, 3])
```

Insipired from example "33.9.1 Converting Python list to a char **" from SWIG documentation http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_nn57, I defined following typemap to handle `unsigned char *` but unfortunately it seems that the typemap is not used. Actually I can use the function only with last argument ignored or set to None.

Python code :

```
    >>> SendAPDU(0x02000000, 2, 0)  
    [36864, [30, 240]]                  #This call is working
    >>> SendAPDU(0x02000000, 2, 0, None)
    [36864, [30, 240]]                  #Also working
```

Then if I try to put a list for data of the command (replacing None in previous example), I receive the following error :

```
>>> SendAPDU(0x02000000, 2, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4]) # HERE IT'S NOT WORKING
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "EMReaderEx.py", line 196, in SendAPDU
        def SendAPDU(self, *args): return _EMReaderEx.EMReaderEx_SendAPDU(self, *args)
    NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'EMReaderEx_SendAPDU'.
      Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
        EMReaderEx::SendAPDU(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned char *)
        EMReaderEx::SendAPDU(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)
        EMReaderEx::SendAPDU(SApdu &)
```

I think we are here in case of  "Wrong type of argument", so I guess that the typemap is not used because I think, but not sure, that the function is not called because of the parameter format doesn't match. So the main question is  how can I pass a list and be sure that will be accepted by the function (and therefore catched by the typemap) ?

I think I missed something because I didn't found any working solution for that, and it should relatively used often.

Here is the code of the typemap code in SWIG .i file:

```
%typemap(in) unsigned char * {
      // Check if is a list 
      unsigned char *ucBuf = NULL;
      if (PyList_Check($input) && PyList_Size($input) > 0) {
        int size = PyList_Size($input);
        int i = 0;
        ucBuf = (unsigned char *) malloc((size+1)*sizeof(unsigned char));
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          PyObject *o = PyList_GetItem($input,i);
          if (PyLong_Check(o))
            ucBuf[i] = (unsigned char) PyLong_AsLong(o);
          else {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"list must contain integers");
            free(ucBuf);
            return NULL;
          }
        }
      } 
      $1 = &ucBuf[0];
    }

    %typemap(freearg) unsigned char * {
        if($1 != NULL)
            free( $1);
    }
```

In Resume, how to do the SWIG typemap to call C++ function :

```
SRpdu * SendAPDU(unsigned int uiAPDU, unsigned int ucLE, unsigned int ucLC, unsigned char * pucDataBuf);
```

Like that from python:

```
SendAPDU(0x02000000, 2, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Any help is welcome
Thanks in advance

p.s. Sorry if my english is bad, it's not my native language.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [module arrays.](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#module-array)

In particular, you are looking to call `fromlist`. If you are using a list to pass instead of a string just because you think that's what you should do, there is a string function available, `fromstring`. Either way, you can simply initialize the array with format specifier `'B'` (notice that capital).

Example usage:

```
array ('B', [1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 6, 0, 6])
```

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your reply.  I tried again with an array, but I got the same error again. Or maybe I misunderstood what you meant. 
`>>> data = array.array('B', [1,2,3,4])
>>> e.SendAPDU(0x13A00000, 0x00, 0x04, data)
`

Comment: I didn't understand why you said "If you are using a list to pass instead of a string just because you think that's what you should do". Is it better to use string in Python ? 
Based on this I tried to use a string, and it works ;-). The format is not very friendly but I can live with that. 
`>>> data = '\x01\x02\x03\x04'
>>> e.SendAPDU(0x13A00000, 0x00, 0x04, data)
Command passed
Status Word : 9000`

Comment: I still didn't find what I want for now. But I stopped to investigate in this way and I think I will used COM interface instead of wrapping C++ to Python. But anyway any responses is still welcome (also for my commencts above).